# WPF ScrollViewer Horizontal containing Itemcontrol doesn't clip / adds scroll

Tags: wpf, layout

I'm trying to have several Items (in this case buttons for testing) in a horizontal scroll viewer, so you can scroll to the left and the right.
Somehow this is not working, eather the total control, that contains the ScrollViewer resizes it self (so it fits all items) or the items don't get scrollable and so floating over and not getting cut at the border. See this image as example:

[Scrollviewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp8cy.png)

In the picture, the Scrollview would normally end at the end of the line on top of it...

The code is the following:

```
 <ScrollViewer x:Name="scroller" Grid.Column="1" CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="5"  Foreground="{x:Null}">
                    <ItemsControl Margin="5,0">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <Button Width="180" Height="80" Margin="5,0"/>
                        <Button Width="180" Height="80" Margin="5,0"/>
    ...
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to ensure that the ScrollViewer stays a constant size, set it's Width and MaxWidth so that it is constant. It may also help to change the horizontal alignment to center.

Eg.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scroller" Grid.Column="1" CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="5" Width="100" MaxWidth="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="{x:Null}">
```